# How to empty a Map<String List<String>>

Tags: java, dictionary

In my method I have a Map that contains a List for the mapped type

```
private static Map<String, List<String>> myMap;
```

It throws an `UnsupportedOperationException` when I try to use the `clear()` method of Map

How do I empty it?

Comment: How do you instantiate the map / where do you get the map from?

Comment: This map is probably not modifiable. How do you initialize it?

Comment: What is the type of the object?

Comment: Generally, call `clear()`. What implementation of `Map` are you using that's throwing this `UnsupportedOperationException`?

Comment: What is the output of `myMap.getClass().getName()`?

Comment: I'm using the Map to store the http headers of a web page, but I want to clear them before I get the next page

Comment: @user2566468 in this case: can't you just set ``myMap`` to ``null`` since you don't need the whole map anymore? And: won't this "next page" overwrite your map variable anyway?

Comment: for gparyani: java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap

Comment: Hmm, so why would `UnmodifiableMap.clear()` be an issue...

Answer (score 3):

[`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is an interface. The problem is not visible here. This exception is raised by the implementation you're using of `Map`

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
myMap = new HashMap<>();
```

It seems that you are using a map implementation that doesn't support that operation (For example `UnmodifiableMap`). Try to debug it and check in runtime what concrete type it is.

Comment: ...using `myMap.getClass()` and its methods.

Comment: @assylias you got it right, i just want to do something tricky  :)